# What words do we use to refer to a deal that favors one party in an agreement?

Tags: phrase-request

What do we call an agreement that dishonestly favors one side in the long run (e.g., a country pretending to pay the debt of another and in exchange gain control of its port for 100 years).

I prefer a two words phrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like a ***one-sided*** agreement.

Definitions of [*one-sided*](https://www.wordnik.com/words/one-sided) include:

> - biased in favour of one faction or demographic group
> - favoring one person or side over another; partial; unjust; unfair

A recent news blog used the word like this:

> It's critical that international institutions monitor these arrangements and find ways to block those that are **one-sided** or benefit only the wealthy.
>
> <sup>**Source**: ["Land Grabs" in Agriculture: Fairer Deals Needed to Ensure Opportunity for Locals](https://www.huffingtonpost.com/danielle-nierenberg/land-grabs-in-agriculture_b_909926.html) by Danielle Nierenberg</sup>